# Analysis of repeated measures at different timing

Tags: repeated-measures, group-differences

I'd like to ask how can analyse data of different patients if they have repeated measures at different timing. How can I group repeated measures to each patient in order to have descriptive data of frequencies and how can I make tha analysis? 
I've got a number of patients with the same diagnosis but different clinical features (eg karyotype, chronological age, bone age etc). They all perform the same analysis with different timing (at different ages) and under different therapies. I'd like to know how to group them by the ID to make a descriptive analysis of my group of patients and how to analyse their samples making a correlation both withe the age and with the therapy at each time of the evaluation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like you need a mixed model.

Comment: could you please give me more information about it?

Comment: I recommend Raudenbush & Bryk (2002) as an intro text

Comment: Plenty of material on this site https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model?sort=votes&pageSize=15